# "Unretrieved" value in the table field

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012, morph-x

I have form with several controls. When I fill these controls all of them are saved correctly in the datasource table except of one realEdit control. It says "Unretrieved" in the table. I have set it's datasource and datafield properties correctly, so what can be a reason of it and how to solve it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Unretrieved" fields are newly created fields which AX 2012 AX by error treats badly. It may also appear if a form query does not contain a field in the datasource field list.

You problem is solved by restarting the client or the AOS or both. Or in the second case just add the field to the query field list.

Comment: In table explorer, you will often see the infamous "unretrieved" in fields assigned to country-specifc or configuration-key-related fields. This is due to locked configuration keys or different user's company country.

Answer (score 3):

1.- Recompile and restore table. Check fields with Table explorer; if table explorer doesn't show your field(s) properly, certainly ypur form won't do. So, if this fails, goto 3

2.- Recompile and restore form. Generate incremental CIL. Check it. If fail, goto 3

3.- Restart Ax client and retry steps 1+2. If fail, goto 4

4.- Restart AOS. Retry steps 1+2.